# Is there a way to programatically detect when the user presses F5 button in browser?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a cache that I would like to invalidate whenever user issues a F5 request in the browser. I am running a JSF 2.0 application. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So..basically when a page is reloaded/refreshed? Or you're looking to track the F5 key specifically?

Comment: @kolossus I am looking to track inside Java code when the page is reloaded or refreshed.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostBack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback()) to check whether a page request is a reload of the same page. An ideal spot for this would be in a `<f:viewAction/>` ( new with JSF-2.2) or `preRenderView` event.

1. Define the backing bean method

   ```
   public static boolean isPostback() {
      return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback();
   }
   ```
2. Use either

   - [`<f:viewAction/>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewAction.html)

     ```
     <f:metadata>
          <f:viewAction action="#{bean.isPostBack}" onPostBack="true"/>
     </f:metadata>
     ```
   - `f:event`

     ```
     <f:metadata>
          <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.isPostBack}"/>
     </f:metadata>
     ```

---

**OR**

You could skip the whole backing bean `isPostBack` check altogether and directly execute the cache-clearing method directly from the page.

- [`<f:viewAction/>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewAction.html)

  ```
      <f:metadata>
           <f:viewAction action="#{bean.clearCache}" rendered="#{facesContext.postBack}" onPostBack="true"/>
      </f:metadata>
  ```
- `f:event`

  ```
      <f:metadata>
           <f:event type="preRenderView" rendered="#{facesContext.postBack}" listener="#{bean.clearCache}"/>
      </f:metadata>
  ```

The benefit with this approach is that you write less code, and your cache clearing mechanism still executes *only* when the request is a post back

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be helpful you can detect any key press with key code.

Refer this link for key codes.
https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Keyboard.html

```html
<rich:hotKey key="f5" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 116) return false;" handler="return false;" disableInInput="true" />
<rich:hotKey key="ctrl+R" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 123) return false;" handler="return false;" disableInInput="true" />
<rich:hotKey key="ctrl+f5" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 154) return false;" handler="return false;" disableInInput="true" />
```

Comment: This piece of code i have used to disable the key press.

Answer (score 0):

I've uploaded a running F5 detector project on [the BootsFaces demo collection on GitHub](https://github.com/stephanrauh/BootsFaces-Examples/tree/master/F5Recognition)  and written [a short blog post](http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/how-to-detect-a-page-reload-in-jsf/). Basically, the the answer of Kolossus is correct. The ViewAction is also triggered on the first page load, so I added a couple of lines to detect that, too.

Comment: What if user has same page open in multiple browser windows/tabs?

Comment: @BalusC Good hint, like always. It wasn't part of my use case, so I didn't investigate it. As far as I remember, multi-tab support requires you to use an extension like CODI, so we'd have to make use of that. Correct me if I'm wrong - I probably am, like I've said, I never had to support multiple tabs or windows before.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that i have implemented on [beyondjava](https://www.beyondjava.net/how-to-detect-a-page-reload-in-jsf)

```
<f:metadata>
   <f:viewAction action="#{f5Detector.checkF5}" onPostBack="true"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Java class (just changed ManagedBean to Named)

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;

@SessionScoped
@Named
public class F5Detector {
    private String previousPage = null;

    public void checkF5() {
        String msg = "";
        UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
        String id = viewRoot.getViewId();
        if (previousPage != null && (previousPage.equals(id))) {
            // It's a reload event
        }
        previousPage = id;
    }
}
```