# J2EE fire method after authentication

Tags: forms, jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am using form based authentication with JavaEE and glassfish and I am looking for a way to fire a method straight after login. So I have the regular `j_security_check` form

```
<form method="post" action="j_security_check" name="loginForm">
    <h:inputText id="j_username" autocomplete="off" />
    <br/>
    <h:inputSecret id="j_password" autocomplete="off"/>
    <br/>
    <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Login"/>
    <h:commandButton type="reset" value="Clear"/>
</form>
```

and I want on successful login to fire a method ONLY ONCE. I have thought of adding the code I want to run on the first page's post construct method but that would fail in case someone reloads the page. And even if it didn't I am sure there are more neat ways of doing so.

Comment: You have some options. To first address your concern, you can [avoid re-executing a method by checking the `isPostBack` attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036546/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-detect-when-the-user-presses-f5-button-in-brow/26060740#26060740). Another approach is to use programmatic JavaEE login

Comment: You could use programmatic `login` method from servlet API and also invoke your method there. [Simple example](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glxce.html#glxef).