# Reset session variable in java

Tags: httpsession

> I work on a multi-company application, after login create session, I make manipulations on many forms and display data, then I return to the button and change the company, however I still find the data of the old company, my question is how to reset the data of all pages and forms without disconnecting, I found the solutions below but it did not meet my need
>
> > empty session with GetExternalContext (). getsessionmap () context. Clear ();
> >      also with context.httpsession.removeAttribute ();
> >     and with session .Invalidate ();

Comment: I found the solution by following this tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036546/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-detect-when-the-user-presses-f5-button-in-brow

Comment: the best solution is change session : @Scop("session") par @Scop("request")